# Как избавиться от абсолютных путей в index.js webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, path, electron

Есть простой проект созданный при помощи Electron-forge в файлах .webpack/main/index.js и .webpack/main_window/index.js присутствуют абсолютные пути от которых необходимо избавиться.

После сборки проекта в файле .webpack/main/index.js появляются строки вида:

```
d.register(s,"logPath","G:\\MyRepositories\\WebPackProject\\my-project\\src\\utils\\logger.ts"),
d.register(c,"nowTs","G:\\MyRepositories\\WebPackProject\\my-project\\src\\utils\\logger.ts")
```

После запуска проекта в файле .webpack/main_window/index.js появляются строки вида:

```
reactHotLoader.register(increment, "increment", "G:\\MyRepositories\\WebPackProject\\my-project\\src\\renderer\\store\\counter\\actions.ts");
reactHotLoader.register(loadCount, "loadCount", "G:\\MyRepositories\\WebPackProject\\my-project\\src\\renderer\\store\\counter\\actions.ts");
```

В webpack.main.config.js:

```
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
        },
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'), 'node_modules']
    },
```

Так же пробовал:

```
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.join('../../src'),
        },
        modules: [path.join('../../node_modules'), 'node_modules']
    },
```

Как можно избавиться от абсолютных путей? Необходимо получить"..\..\src\renderer\store\counter\actions.ts", что бы не отображался диск и местонахождение проекта.

Comment: возможно то что вам нужно https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5762

Comment: @MidNightElf Может я что то делаю не верно, но данный способ не подошёл.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445612/import-using-absolute-path-using-webpack-and-electron я кое-как повторил ваш конфиг, ошибка была похожая. мне помогло вот это